Longest forced checkmate on cylinder board
What is the longest possible forced checkmate where:

White has a king and rook
Black has only a king
The board is 8x8 but the a-file and h-file are joined (so the board is a cylinder)
Pieces still move normally
50-move, 75-move rules do not apply

I know a mate in 3:
   [FEN "4k3/8/8/4K3/4R3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

   1. Ke6 Kd8 (1... Kf8 2. Rg4 Ke8 3. Rg8#) 2. Rc4 Ke8 3. Rc8#

